# Regular expression to find System.out.print

Tags: java, regex, regular-language

I try to create one regular expression allows find all System.out.println or print inside all my java classes.

I need to delete all outputs.

Thanks.

Comment: Find `System\.out\.print\([^)]+\)` and replace by empty string

Comment: It's tricky due to the arguments within the parentheses. There can be other parentheses, etc.
Is it OK to find them all with a pattern, then process them manually?
Btw, which tools are you using? Grep? Eclipse?

Comment: I tried use the regular expression @Tushar gave with search of eclipse and works nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"System\\.out\\.println"
```

use this regex and replace all with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for but if you are using eclipse to do your development then this would be your best approach.

If you want to search in files: Ctrl+H and then choose tab File Search. Enter your search parameter and it shows all the files where sysout is used. Hope it helps...